# C# Automapper how to create a list with nested mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map into the list, which supposes to have two other lists inside. Is it doable? I looked at the documentation but couldn't find what I needed unless I misunderstood something.

`CompanyActivityReport.cs`

```
public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
public string OrganisationName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> OrganisationSubTypeID { get; set; } 

public CompanyActivityReportTask ReportTask{get; set;}
public CompanyActivityReportNote ReportNotes{get; set;}
```

My mapping:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<OrganisationMain,CompanyActivityReport>();
    c.CreateMap<TaskMain, CompanyActivityReportTask>();
    c.CreateMap<NoteMain, CompanyActivityReportNote>();

});
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
List<CompanyActivityReport> TestList = mapper.Map<List<CompanyActivityReport>>(OrganisationMainsList).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please add more info on `OrganisationMainsList`?

Comment: Hi, Ermiya! OrganisationMainList is a queried list from OrganisationMain, however, it's just an example as this mapping from that list, does not give me an expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you problably need to map each item individually like:

```
            List<CompanyActivityReport> TestList = OrganisationMainsList.Select(x => mapper.Map<CompanyActivityReport>(x))
```

Edit: Select return a Enumerable so if you wish to mantain the behaviour a .ToList() is required:

```
 List<CompanyActivityReport> TestList = OrganisationMainsList.Select(x => mapper.Map<CompanyActivityReport>(x)).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Davi, thank you for Your suggestion, unfortunately, It does not work, ReportTask and ReportNotes remains null.